# Font-weight of scaled square bracket delimiters in Beamer

Tags: beamer, brackets, math-fonts

In my beamer documents, the square bracket delimiters have a visibly more heavy vertical line when unscaled compared to their scaled versions, where the vertical line is thinner. Other delimiters are fine.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    
    \[
    [ \qquad \bigl[
    \]
    
    \[
    \{ \qquad \bigl\{
    \]
    
    \[
    ( \qquad \bigl(
    \]
    
    \[
    \langle \qquad \bigl\langle 
    \]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration of vertical lines in square bracket delimiters]

This issue does not occur with the article class, where the vertical line of the square bracket is thinner in normal size.

Is there anything that can be done about this?

Edit: This why I think that this looks ugly: in the formula below, th square brackets appear inconsistently weighted.

```
\begin{align*}
P[B]&=P[B\cap S]=P\bigl[B\cap (A_1\cup \dots\cup A_n) \bigr] \\
&=P\bigl[(B\cap A_1)\cup\dots \cup(B\cap A_n)\bigr] \\
&=P[B\cap A_1]+\dots+P[B\cap A_n] \\
&=P[B\mid A_1]\cdot P[A_1]+\dots+P[B\mid A_n]\cdot P[A_n]
\end{align*}
```

[image: Illustrating example]

Comment: You'd get the same with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}`

Comment: So is this really a sansmathfonts problem? I don't understand why the sans serif fonts have this effect on the square bracket...

Comment: That's how the [ looks like in sans serif computer modern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[` you see in the default beamer font is how a bracket looks like in sans serif computer modern. The sans serif font is a bit heavier, so it makes sense that the [ is also a bit heavier than in the serif font.

If you prefer maths fonts like in the article class, you could use the `professionalfonts` font theme, which will stop beamer from changing math fonts:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
    
    \[
    [ \qquad \bigl[
    \]
    
    \[
    \{ \qquad \bigl\{
    \]
    
    \[
    ( \qquad \bigl(
    \]
    
    \[
    \langle \qquad \bigl\langle 
    \]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you'd like sans serif, pick another font which has brackets you like. Just one possible example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{arevtext,arevmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
abc P 
  
\begin{align*}
P[B]&=P[B\cap S]=P\bigl[B\cap (A_1\cup \dots\cup A_n) \bigr] \\
&=P\bigl[(B\cap A_1)\cup\dots \cup(B\cap A_n)\bigr] \\
&=P[B\cap A_1]+\dots+P[B\cap A_n] \\
&=P[B\mid A_1]\cdot P[A_1]+\dots+P[B\mid A_n]\cdot P[A_n]
\end{align*}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I am using profesionalfonts as well as the sansmathfonts package - and then the problem re-appears. (I am loading lots of packages, I was just trying to distill things down to a minimal working example): 

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}

Comment: @HorstHohberger with sansmathsfonts you get the same sans serif [ from computer modern modern which you don't like. Choose a font which you like.

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but if the [ comes from computer modern, is it a scaling issue with the computer modern fonts?

Comment: That's just how the symbol looks like

Comment: Thank you for your patience. It's just that I think it looks very unsatisfactory. I have edited my question to illustrate this, but I am willing to accept that this is just the way things are with the CM font. Unless someone else chimes in within the next 48 hours, I will accept your answer.